# Why do I need to set environment variables for Python to make Scrapy work?

Tags: python, environment-variables, scrapy

I have just got Scrapy set up on my machine (Windows Vista 64 bit, Python.org version 2.7, 64 bit shell). I have tried running the command 'scrapy startproject myproject' and got the seemingly standard error message of 'scrapy is not a recognised command.

A lot of the other people who have asked this question have been advised that they need to set up environment variables for Python in Windows. I'm not entirely sure why I am supposed to do this to be honest. Could someone please explain?

Comment: I think you need `C:\Python27\Scripts` to be added to your path

Comment: try `set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts` from the command line and try again

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Hello again Padraic. So in the above example should it be 'C:\Python27>set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts'?

Comment: no just enter in cmd as it is, it is not a permanent solution, I just wanted to see if it rectified your problem

Comment: @PadraicCunningham no, im afraid it didnt.

Comment: post the output of `import sys sys.path` from a python shell

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ['C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-3.4.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56610/discussion-between-padraic-cunningham-and-user3045351).

Answer (score 4):

Windows uses the environment variable called PATH to identify a command in comand prompt and directs to the folder in which the command is associated with. For instance, when you install `Python`, it appends it's location in your system to the PATH variable, so that when you call it in cmd (type in  `python`), it knows where to look and calls the appropriate program/s at that location.

Comment: @idiot.py so if im getting the above error message, what do i need to set my python environment variable as? thanks

Comment: You can't say I'm not honest! I plan to evolve the username as I evolve :)

Comment: I'm not a scrappy expert, but PATH can be changed via control panel. Search up `environment variables` and open `edit environment variables` as admin. Click `Environment variables` and find PATH and edit it, entering Scrappy's dictionary with a semi-colon at the end. Then you should be set (hopefully :) ).

Comment: @idiot.py I've found the environment variables and the variable path, which currently has 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared' in it...how and where do I need to amend that exactly?

Comment: do i just put C:\Python27; on the end?

Comment: If scrappy is a module you can import into python, then it should be located in PythonXX\Lib\site-packages. Find the dictionary for scrappy, and insert the address at the end (semi colons separate all the addresses). `C:\Python27` be on there too, as part of a healthy install, so insert that on to the end as well.

Comment: @idiot.py So you mean 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scrapy'?

Comment: @idiot.py nearly there...which location should i run 'scrapy startproject myproject' from? ive tried C:\Python, C:\Python27\Scripts and C:\Python27\Scrapy so far...all throw up the same error as before...

Comment: You should be able to enter `scrapy startproject myproject` in cmd on its own thanks to the PATH variable. This is what it's for; saving having to enter the full address for a command very time.

Comment: @idiot.py...do i need to use a version number in the scrapy command? for example i type 'pip2.7 install scrapy' when using that rather than just 'pip install scrapy'.

Comment: There should be no need to include version numbers. If there is a naming clash, i.e. different versions of pip with the same call name, then I would remove the unwanted versions and leave the needed one as the sole address with that particular call name.